# How to select all the rows of a JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, jcheckbox

I am trying to make a JTable which stores boolean checkboxes, previous browsing time, sites and their URL. I have added a menu bar in it which contains two menu items **Remove**  and **Select All**.

My problem is with **Select All** .I want to select all rows of table by clicking it. But when i click it, it makes all elements of **checkBox**(given below) true but doesn't show it in the table. **I mean i can't see any selected tick marks in the table**.

Here is my code below. Where did i go wrong? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
public class HistList extends JPanel {

JTable table = new JTable();
Object[][] data;
public static ArrayList<String> timeList;
public static ArrayList<String> namelist;
public static ArrayList<String> locTable;
JMenuItem remove = new JMenuItem("Remove");
JMenuItem selectAll = new JMenuItem("Select All");
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
int i = 0;
Hello hello;
public static ArrayList<Boolean> checkBox = new ArrayList<>();

HistList(ArrayList timeList, ArrayList namelist, ArrayList locTable) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    count = new ArrayList<>();
    this.dateList = dateList;
    this.locTable = locTable;
    this.namelist = namelist;
    this.timeList = timeList;
    this.repeatCount = repeatCount;
    String[] title = {" ", "Time", "Name", "Location"};
        data = new Object[this.title.size()][4];
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                if (k == 0) {
                    data[j][k] = false;
                } else if (k == 1) {
                    data[j][k] = this.timeList.get(j);
                } else if (k == 2) {
                    data[j][k] = this.namelist.get(j);
                } else if (k == 3) {
                    data[j][k] = this.locTable.get(j);
                }
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        model.addRow(data[i]);
        checkBox.add(false);
    }
    this.table = new JTable(model);
    this.table.setShowGrid(false);

    this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);
    Dimension size = new Dimension(510, 380);
    this.scrollPane.setPreferredSize(size);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();
               //do something
            }
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                try {
                    JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();
                    int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                    //do something
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HistList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    JMenuBar organize = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Organize");
    menu.add(remove);
    menu.add(selectAll);
    selectAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println("in select all");
            checkBox.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++)
            model.setValueAt(true, i,0 );
            table.revalidate();
            table.validate();
        }
    });
    selectAll.setEnabled(true);
    remove.setEnabled(false);
    remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            int num = 0;
            for (int j = model.getRowCount() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                System.out.println(model.getValueAt(j, 2));
                System.out.println(model.getRowCount());
                if (checkBox.get(j)) {
                    model.removeRow(j);
                    model.fireTableDataChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    organize.add(menu);

    JPanel finale = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    finale.add(organize, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    finale.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(finale);
}

public void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("History");
    HistList newContentPane = new HistList(timeList, namelist, locTable);
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); 
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public MyTableModel() {
        super(new String[]{" ", "Time", "Name", "Location"}, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }
        Class clazz = String.class;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                clazz = Boolean.class;
                break;
        }
        return clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return column == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        if (aValue instanceof Boolean && column == 0) {

            Vector rowData = (Vector) getDataVector().get(row);
            rowData.set(0, (boolean) aValue);
            if (checkBox.size() > row) {
                checkBox.remove(row);
            }
            checkBox.add(row, (Boolean) aValue);
            System.out.println(row + " " + checkBox.toString());
            if (checkBox.contains(true)) {
                remove.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                remove.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that may help. Clicking the button sets the Boolean value of the checkbox cells to true:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableCheckBox extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public TableCheckBox() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        Object[] columnNames = {"Check"};
        Object[][] data = { {false}, {false}, {false}, {false} };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return Boolean.class;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Check All");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                for (int row=0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    table.setValueAt(true, row, 0);
                }
            } 
        } );
        add(btn);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableCheckBox frame = new TableCheckBox();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(150, 150);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply basic code of `JTable` in selecting the data/s. Ex. `jTable.SelectAll()` which allow the user to select all the data within the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (buttonclicked) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            jTable1.setValueAt(true, i, 0);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
            jTable1.setValueAt(false, i, 0);
        }
    }
```

This code Selects All checkboxs on the same column and deselects when you ,for example , uncheck checkbox.